# how do i split dsx file into multiple files using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following single file and wanted to split into multiple files in python.

file name = `Project.dsx` and contents are as below -

> BEGIN HEADER  Project  END HEADER
>
> BEGIN DSJOB   Identifier "JOB1" END DSJOB
>
> BEGIN DSJOB   Identifier "JOB2" END DSJOB
>
> BEGIN DSJOB   Identifier "JOB3" END DSJOB

I would like to create one file for each job . i.e. job1.dsx ,job2.dsx,job3.dsx in python.

The header part is for project so the content from begin header to end header can be ignored.

Please advise... Thank You

Comment: Why do you want to use Python for this? Use another programming language you are more familiar with, or learn some basics of Python reading documentation of `open` file, `read`, `split`, `write` and about looping over items of lists with for example `for line in list_of_lines:`.

Comment: Thank you ..Yes i have managed to do it using basic python... trying to know if the problem was already solved before.

Comment: I was really, really surprised failing to find on stackoverflow or elsewhere a Python solution to exactly this kind of goal. The easiest approach is in my eyes reading the entire file, then splitting it on `BEGIN DSJOB Identifier` using the `re` module, taking the headers of the split parts as file names and saving the files. Glad to hear you have solved it yourself. There is sure a ready to use solution online for such standard task ... but it seems to be not easy to find. I suggest you answer your own question here on stackoverflow, so that future seekers can profit from it.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do the job (see my comment to the answer):

```
import re
pat_1 = "BEGIN DSJOB Identifier "
pat_2 = '"(.*?)"'
with open("Project.dsx") as f:
    S = f.read()
    L = re.split(pat_1, S)[1:] # elim. empty string
    for s in L:
        fnam = re.search(pat_2, s).group(1)
        print(fnam)
        with open(fnam+".dsx","w") as fw:
            fw.write(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is not too late. I prepared Windows executable to do exactly PK39565 asked.
https://github.com/forest416/dsxcut/blob/main/bin/dsxcut.exe
It is standalone executable, has no dependency on perl/python environment.

It handles job, route and parameter set. It also put output file under sub-folder same as in DataStage.

For Linux, build from source by yourself. Build instruction included in the repository.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).